# how can turn on camera and capture a photo in div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, video

I wanna turn on camera in a `div` element. I use below structure:

```
return (
    <div id="container">
         <video id="video" width="640" height="480"></video>
            {testFunction()}
    </div>
);

function testFunction() {
var video = document.getElementById('video');
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.play();
  });
}}
```

but, it gives error!! `video.srcObject = stream;` and `video.play();` give error.. what shoudl I do? thank you!

Comment: Can you post the errors you get from "video.srcObject = stream;" and "video.play();"?

Comment: `Object is possibly 'null'.  TS2531
    video.srcObject = stream;`

Comment: I've tried the code given, In my laptop with a camera didn't give any error and my camera played successfully. Do you have camera in your pc or laptop? Maybe if camera doesn't exist it gives error.

Comment: I found that its error is because of typescript!! I should tell the type of "video" variation. I donot know how?!
`var video: HTMLVideoElement = document.getElementById('video');` ?!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
function testFunction() {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');

  if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(
      function(stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
          video.play();
        };
    });
  }
```